# D3 v4 Zooming Partition Layout in X dimension only

Tags: d3.js

Trying to wrap my head around this particular use case of D3 v4 zooming.  My example so far is available here:

http://bl.ocks.org/gmarler/f6d17432f6eea34318bff477eb9ebd27

I'm able to get my initial Partition Layout to draw as required (I've left out complexities such as text positioning and color), but I'm not getting very far with zooming properly.

The goal is to zoom whenever one of the svg rect elements is clicked on.

And by "zoom", I mean something somewhat different than the stated default behaviors:

- Completely disable anything other than a click on an element - no drag, panning, or mouse wheel activity normally associated with D3 zoom.
- When an svg rect element is clicked on, the element expands (or contracts) in the X dimension only, such that its left side abuts the left side of the top level svg's g container, and its right side abuts the right side of the top level svg's g container.

  - In other words, the element clicked on becomes exactly the width of the chart.
- All other g/rect elements vertically "above" the clicked one should scale/translate appropriately.
- All other elements vertically "below" the clicked one don't really need to change, as the one we've clicked on will take up 100% of the width of the chart container.

So, here's how far I've gone:

- I've calculated the scaling factor (k) - not sure I've done it right.  The goal is to set the scaling factor to whatever will make the width of the clicked element expand/contract to the width of the svg.
- And I've calculated the transform for x (tx) to be whatever will cause the left side of the g element encapsulating the rect element to align with the left side of the svg.
- Using k and tx, I create a zoom transform with d3.zoomIdentity.translate(tx, 0).scale(k)
- Now I select all of the g elements that contain rects, tear the current transform="translate(x,y)" apart, and apply the zoom transform to the x portion of the translate - this should move the left side of the element to the left side of the svg
- Next, I select the rect under each g element, and apply the zoom transform to the width attribute

This seems to get me closer to the end goal, but I'm sure I'm missing something:

- Is it really necessary for me to tear apart the transform="translate(x,y)" the way I am for the g elements?
- If I click on certain elements more than once, the scaling keeps increasing.  I need to both:

  - Keep the original zoom ratio so that I can reset to it, or go back to it simply by clicking on the lowest rect element
  - If an element is clicked on, it's already at 100% width - I need to never allow scaling past 100% width
- clicking on any given element the first time expands it to 100% width as expected, but not all elements' ancestors properly scale - I don't care if the the ancestors expand either end past the edge of the viewport, but some of the ancestor elements leave the viewport entirely, which I cannot account for.